# Change permissions for file

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have business account in Google Drive with 2 users: User and AdminUser(Super Admin role).
AdminUser creates folder TestFolder, and share it (Read and Write) with User.
User creates file TestFile in shared folder (TestFolder) and in sharing options for this file leave only his account (removes AdminUser account).

My application (C#) connect to the Google Drive (as AdminUser), and when I trying

```
ChildrenResource.ListRequest request1 = Service.Children.List(“TestFolderID”);
do
{
  try
  {
    ChildList children1 = request1.Fetch();
    foreach (ChildReference child in children1.Items)
    {
      try
      {
        PermissionList permissions = Service.Permissions.List(child.Id).Fetch();            
      }
      catch (Exception exc)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
      }
    }
    request.PageToken = children1.NextPageToken;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    request.PageToken = null;
  }
} while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));
```

I got 
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

File not found: 1O-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXx[404]
Errors [ Message[File not found: 1O-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXx] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]]

How Can I change permissions?

I know that in web GUI Super Admin user has a menu where he can transfer the ownership of the all files from one user to another user. How can I do this operation in C# code? I can't find it in Google Drive SDK.